# Does a current workaround for babel and indexing Roman-numeral page numbers exist?

Tags: indexing, babel

Until recently, one could redefine `\textlatin` to expand to its argument in order to allow index entries using Roman numerals and babel when a non-ASCII encoding is loaded together with ASCII encodings.

The recent changes to babel now make that obsolete. If any non-ASCII encoding is present, an encoding selection is made, along with a font switch. This is done via `\AtBeginDocument` and the process related to `\ensureascii`.

Consider this MWE:

```
%!TEX program=pdflatex

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\meaning\thepage

\index{\string\thepage}

\mainmatter
\meaning\thepage
\index{\string\thepage}

\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `.idx` file will have:

```
\indexentry{\string\thepage}{{\fontencoding  {T1}\selectfont  i}}
\indexentry{\string\thepage}{1}
```

That will not play well with makeindex for similar reasons as the former use of `\textlatin`. One will lose all one's index entries in the front matter.

Is there any elegant workaround that anyone has discovered? Or perhaps stick with an old version of babel?

I hesitate to use sed to stroke the `.idx` file in conjunction with latexmk, which otherwise does a marvelous job at creating the document on which I am working.

Although I understand why this design decision is quite helpful in many places, it does complicate indexing.

Comment: Depending on how the `LGR` encoding is used, just something like `\renewcommand\BabelNonASCII{}` in the preamble could do the trick. Interestingly this issue has never been reported as a bug (and I think it's a bug). I'll investigate a general solution.

Comment: Sorry I didn't report it as a bug; there had been previous internet chatter on the matter of `\textlatin` so I assumed it simply is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `\ensureascii` robust against `\edef` and `\write` expansion; then use a terrible hack to get rid of `\ensureascii` when the index file is written out.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \robustify\ensureascii
  \def\@@@wrindexm@m#1#2{%
    \if@filesw
      \global\let\@gtempa\@idxfile
      \endgroup % end \@sanitize
      \begingroup
      \let\ensureascii\@firstofone
      \everyeof{\noexpand}%
      \immediate\write\@gtempa{\string\indexentry{#1}{\scantokens{#2\@empty}}}%
    \fi
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\meaning\thepage

\index{\string\thepage}

\mainmatter
\meaning\thepage
\index{\string\thepage}

\backmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The contents of the `.idx` file will be

```
\indexentry{\string\thepage}{i}
\indexentry{\string\thepage}{1}
```

Some words of explanation. `memoir` writes the index entries in the aux file and makes the idx file(s) only at end document. When the index entry is first written out, `\ensureascii` is expanded. So the first thing to do is making it robust against expansion during a write operation. Next we want to get rid of it when the idx file is written. Here the problem is that the arguments to `\@@@wrindexm@m` are read verbatim, so we need to kill the scope of `\@sanitize` and reread the second argument with the standard setup, locally making `\ensureascii`.

This will only work with `memoir`, of course.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. It seems that makeindex doesn't want to resolve forms of `\indexentry` where there is anything but numbers\letters in the second argument. _The Latex Companion_ p.649f. puts formatting, etc. for `\indexentry` in the first argument. Its solution is either to use `|` followed by a command, `|see` `|seealso` `|hyperpage` or to redefine `\index` or put it in a user-defined macro. The old way using `\textlatin` allowed for a quick and dirty workaround that effectively got rid of it in the second argument. Memoir, etc., also redefine `\index`.

Comment: @user32053 The hacks get even more horrible, but this works for `memoir`.

Comment: @egreg How would the horrible hack look with `\usepackage[makeindex]{imakeidx}` and a normal class (scrbook in my case, but imho it is would be the same as with book).

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to zap `babel`'s redefinition of `\@roman` and `\@Roman`.

```
...
\makeatletter
\let\save@roman\@roman
\let\save@Roman\@Roman
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\let\@roman\save@roman
\let\@Roman\save@Roman
\makeatother
...
```

This won't work if you want to *create* Roman numerals when the language is switched to Greek, but at least it is simple and self-documenting.

Comment: This also works with memoir, as well as with non-memoir documents. BTW, I link to this question page in the nameauth documentation because the issue has come up. Both solutions here should be helpful to people.

Comment: Thx! See also https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/170 .