# "Greek" language in Babel makes "index" fail for roman-numbered pages

Tags: babel, font-encodings, makeindex

The following MWE works fine:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
% \usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
foo\index{foo}
\mainmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But if I uncomment the `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` I get an error (even though the MWE doesn't contain any Greek text). My `.idx` file has changed from

```
\indexentry{foo}{i}
```

to

```
\indexentry{foo}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  i}}
```

and the `.ilg` file says

```
!! Input index error (file = test.idx, line = 1):
   -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.
```

How can I get rid of the unwanted font encoding?

The document was compiled with `latexmk` (with the default options) in TexLive 2016.

Comment: The problem is known and there is a solution: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337741/does-a-current-workaround-for-babel-and-indexing-roman-numeral-page-numbers-exis

Answer (score 6):

Christian Hupfer's comment gives [Does a current workaround for babel and indexing Roman-numeral page numbers exist?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337741/does-a-current-workaround-for-babel-and-indexing-roman-numeral-page-numbers-exis) as an answer, but since I never want to use Roman numerals in Greek text, just restoring the LaTeX definition of `\@roman` after `babel` has "enhanced" it also works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
\let\save@roman\@roman
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\let\@roman\save@roman
\makeatother

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
foo\index{foo}
\mainmatter
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The same idea would also work for `\@Roman`, of course.