# BibLaTeX - Backreferencing citations from frontmatter with Greek language

Tags: biblatex, babel, greek, back-referencing, front-matter

I've encountered a problem with backreferences from my bibliography (biblatex, biber) to the frontmatter of my document when using "greek" as a babel option in my document. The following seems to be a minimal example. It does not matter if greek is the main language or an additonal one (see commented line).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
    backref=true,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

%\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {Title},
publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

Here I reference the book \cite{key}.

\mainmatter

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The console output starts

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
```

and the error is

```
(backrefstartmatter.aux

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.13 ...}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  i}}{1}
```

The corresponding section of the .aux file is

```
\abx@aux@backref{1}{key}{0}{{\fontencoding  {OT1}\selectfont  i}}{1}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: babel/greek redefines \roman (to ensure that it is always in a latin script) and this quite often leads to problems. See e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337741/does-a-current-workaround-for-babel-and-indexing-roman-numeral-page-numbers-exis/337766#337766

Comment: Did the solution Ulrike linked to work for you? It worked fine for me when I applied it in your MWE (which produced the same error you describe on my machine before applying the patch).

Comment: Thanks Ulrike and Moewe!
I experimented a while with the solution suggested by egreg at the link, but I think it would need some more understanding than I currently have to adapt to my situation (bib rather than index file). It will be a good exercise for me when I have time!

The solution suggested by alephzero, however, I understood and was able to use. I will not need to generate roman numerals when in Greek mode so that's enough for me.
Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I have closed your question as a duplicate, then. I could get egreg's answer to work in your MWE. You just have to copy the stuff between `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` and paste it to your preamble. But maybe your real document is more complicated...